# Deleting a record from table in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to delete a record within a table using Laravel.  I've tried many different things.

I have the following in my view:

```
@foreach($providers as $provider)
<tr>
    <td>{{$provider->{'Provider First Name'} }}</td>
    <td>{{$provider->{'Provider Last Name (Legal Name)'} }}</td>
    <td>{{$provider->{'Provider Credential Text'} }}</td>
    <td><a href="/provider/{{$provider->NPI}}">Link</a> </td>
  <form action="/blah/{{$provider->NPI}}" method="POST">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    <td><button type="submit"> Delete </button> </td>
  </form>
```

@endforeach

I have the following in my routes:

```
Route::post('/blah/{id}', function($id) {

//Get user id for currently logged in user
$user = Auth::id();


//Query UserToProviderMappings table to get record where provider is mapped to user
    $query = DB::table('user_to_provider_mappings')
        ->where('user_id', $user)
        ->where('provider_npi', $id)
        ->delete();

    // $query->delete();

// return back();
```

});;

The view works fine.  When I click delete in the view, I get redirected to a search results page and the record is not deleted in the table.  I did try both post and delete in the route/form.

The search results page I am being redirected to has the following route:

```
Route::resource ('search-results', 'SearchResultsController');
```

And the following in the SearchResultsController:

```
    public function index()
{

    {
        //The search() function is accessed using 'scopeSearch' within NPIData Model


        $providers = NPIData::search()->orderBy('NPI')->paginate(20);

        return view('inc.searchresults', compact('providers'));
    }
```

Comment: provide the controller that returns this view that you keep showing ... what is the search results page? we don't know what that is or how it gets its information, or what other routes you have

Comment: i dont understand what part of this is a problem?

Comment: the form that is in the foreach loop is not working.  It is supposed to be hitting the Route::post('/blah/{id}' and then deleting the record.  It is not hitting that route

Answer (score 1):

You are using Query Builder not Eloquent so you are not dealing with Models, so there is no `delete` method to be calling on anything that could be returned. You are also calling `get` which returns many results not 1 result.

Since you are using Query Builder you should just replace `get()` with `delete()` to do a DELETE query to remove the record(s).

It is entirely possible you are not deleting anything at all though. You should check the result of the `delete()`.

Comment: thanks, I corrected that part but I still am having a problem with the form.  Anytime I click delete, it is automatically returning search results.  I don't have a duplicate route anywhere.  I am using POST

Comment: idk what your controller that is handling that view is doing, you aren't showing it (you are redirecting back to this form)... it is entirely possible your query isn't deleting anything based on the where conditions you have

Comment: now it looks like it is hitting my 'search-results' route and I'm not sure why.
The route for 'search-results' is:  Route::resource ('search-results', 'SearchResultsController');
I changed the route I am working on to: Route::post('/blah/{id}', function($id) to be sure.  
In view:  
<form action="/blah/{{$provider->NPI}}" method="POST">
        {{-- {{ method_field('DELETE') }} --}}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <td><button type="submit"> Delete </button> </td>

Comment: because you are redirecting back ... what is the URL in the address bar, is there a GET route that matches that URI? add all this stuff to your question if it is relevant

Comment: The URL after I submit the form is:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-results?_token=Qlou82V8Q9n1j7g5LMxJpl8FHejvpGZOQTVKwqC3&search=&_token=Qlou82V8Q9n1j7g5LMxJpl8FHejvpGZOQTVKwqC3&_token=Qlou82V8Q9n1j7g5LMxJpl8FHejvpGZOQTVKwqC3&_token=Qlou82V8Q9n1j7g5LMxJpl8FHejvpGZOQTVKwqC3&_token=Qlou82V8Q9n1j7g5LMxJpl8FHejvpGZOQTVKwqC3

Comment: I had a POST route but I'm going to try changing it to GET.  I will remove the return back()

Comment: what ROUTE is showing this form ... add all of this to your question, everything that is relevant to what is happening